# Problem with struct when I split the functions from main

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct in my `main` let's say:

```
struct node
{
    char name[N];
    int num;
    char **group;
    int groupsize;
    struct node * next;
};
```

and I have my functions to other .c and .h files call myfuncs.c.h

myfuncs.h

```
void create_node(struct node **, struct node **, int, int, char **, int);
void display(struct node *head);
void start_joseph(struct node **, int, int);
```

and myfuncs.c

```
void create_node(struct node **, struct node **, int, int, char **, int);
{
  do something;
}

void display(struct node *head);
{
  do something;
}

void start_joseph(struct node **, int, int);
{
  do something;
}
```

but I get this error

```
[Warning] 'struct node' declared inside parameter list
[Warning] its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
```

Should I define the struct to the pre-processor or what?

Comment: *"I have a struct in my main"* -- that's the problem. How will your other code know anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

Put the structure definition in the header before the function declarations that use it.

At minimum, you need a line:

```
struct node;
```

in the header before the function declarations.  Since you don't appear to be trying to create an opaque type (the details of which would be hidden from the code using it), then embedding the entire structure definition is reasonable.  Note that you then delete that definition from the code holding the `main()` function.

What the error message says is that if you write:

```
void create_node(struct node **, struct node **, int, int, char **, int);
```

and there is no previous mention of the type `struct node`, then the type name is created but only exists for that one function declaration.  The next function that refers to `struct node` creates a new type name `struct node` which is different from and incompatible with the previous one.  By declaring `struct node;` at file scope, you're saying "there is a type `struct node`".  Basically, you have to have something outside the scope of a prototype that says "there is a type `struct node`" which the function prototype can then use.

Suggested solution — `myfuncs.h`:

```
#ifndef MYFUNCS_H_INCLUDED
#define MYFUNCS_H_INCLUDED

struct node
{
    char name[N];
    int num;
    char **group;
    int groupsize;
    struct node * next;
};

extern void create_node(struct node **, struct node **, int, int, char **, int);
extern void display(struct node *head);
extern void start_joseph(struct node **, int, int);

#endif /* MYFUNCS_H_INCLUDED */
```

The header guards prevent problems if the file is included multiple times in a single translation unit (source file plus included headers).  I use `extern` on function declarations to match the `extern` needed on variables declared in the header; many people don't.  That choice is up to you and/or the coding guidelines you work with.  Removing the `extern` makes no difference to the result.

Comment: why the use of extern is needed ?

Comment: @KyleeHolcomb — You declare variables in headers; that means you use `extern` to indicate that they’re defined elsewhere.  Using `extern` with variables is virtually mandatory.  For symmetry, I use `extern` with function declarations too. As I said, using `extern` with functions isn’t mandatory (unless I’m in charge of your coding guidelines — then it’s mandatory). I think it is better. Others don’t.  Your choice.

Comment: but they are not defined in my main file. I have only the struct. Should I also define them on my main ?

Comment: I don’t know which “they” or “them" you’re asking about. You have a `main()` function in one source file. It uses the `struct node` type and calls the functions declared in the header, so you must (should) include the header in that file. The functions are defined in their own source file, but you must (should) include the header in that file so that the compiler can cross-check that you’re doing it right. The header is what allows the compiler to ensure that you define and use the functions correctly. So the header is included in every source file that uses the types or functions it declares.

Comment: After email code analysis, we found that the `myfuncs.c` had no `#include` lines in it at all — it needed 5 (`"myfuncs.h"`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>` and `<time.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare node struct at other header file, e.g global.h, and include the global.h in myfuncs.h.

```
  // in the global.h 
 struct node
 {
      char name[N];
      int num;
      char **group;
      int groupsize;
      struct node * next;
  };
  ....    ....
 // in the myfuncs.h
 #include "global.h"
```

Comment: Why create a new header?  Why not simply place the structure definition in the existing header?

Comment: yes, you can define it in the myfuncs.h file, but i think it is a good habit to collect globally used data structure or class in one file.

Comment: OK — I beg to differ, but it is partly a matter of taste.  Generally, you shouldn't make the compiler process lots of structure definitions that it won't need.  You do that by limiting the structure definition to the one file (`myfuncs.h` in this example) that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

In these function declarations

```
void create_node(struct node **, struct node **, int, int, char **, int);
void display(struct node *head);
void start_joseph(struct node **, int, int);
```

the type struct node has the  function prototype scopes of each function declaration and is not visible outside the parameter declaration lists.

The same problem exist with the function definitions. And the warnings

```
[Warning] 'struct node' declared inside parameter list
[Warning] its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
```

point to this.

The declaration of the structure in main has the function main block scope and is also invisible outside the function.

You need at least declare (or define) the structure before the function declarations and the structure shall be already defined before the function definitions.

So move the structure definition from main to a point before the function declarations.

For example

**myfuncs.h**

```
struct node
{
    char name[N];
    int num;
    char **group;
    int groupsize;
    struct node * next;
};

void create_node(struct node **, struct node **, int, int, char **, int);
void display(struct node *head);
void start_joseph(struct node **, int, int);
```